# Axon JpaSagaStore not consisent

Tags: java, axon, axon-framework

When I start a Saga and almost immediately after call JpaSagaStore.findSagas it often returns an empty list. Why is that? Should I be using some kind of caching mechanism to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chances are high that the `UnitOfWork` Axon Framework starts hasn't committed yet. Assuming you invoke the `findSagas` method roughly while the saga event handler is still active.

Another way of putting it: the transaction isn't done yet, so you're requesting it too soon.
I am curious, though, to what end do you need to manually find the saga in the `SagaStore`?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. We have a lot of events that are able to start a specific saga for an association value. However, once one of the events have started the saga all the other events just need to be handled by the saga eventhandler for that specific association value. So if we can check that the saga exists, then we just send the event as an "additional event", otherwise we send it as a "start event".

Because we noticed that the findSagas method isn't reliable we now have to pray that our incoming stream of events always start with a specific event that IS able to start the saga.

Comment: What you're trying to achieve is normal behavior of a Saga when using a Streaming Processor (Tracking or Pooled Streaming). A single Saga instance will handle all (relevant) events sequentially. So if out of several possible events that can be handled, only the first one will start is. Subsequent events will just have the existing Saga instance updated.

Comment: We have 10 different events that can all be the starting event of the Saga instance. Once one of those events start the Saga instance we want the other 9 events to not start a new Saga instance but be processed by the already 'live' Saga instance. All 10 events do share the same association value, they just (might) have different payloads to be processed. Without custom programmatically handling this, I can't see a way to do this with the framework. But i'm rather new to this, so could be i'm not well versed in Axon yet.

Comment: Gotcha, @Rafiek. I've actually hit this twice at users of Axon Framework too. Luckily, in both occasions, we could point to another event that preceded all 'N' events that may start the Saga. So in favor of simplicity with your aforementioned issue, we moved to this one event instead of the entire (although correct) set.

Comment: So, in short, we looked for a common association that occurred before the rest. 
Another way you could tackle this, is by making the process the saga triggers idempotent. Or, even better, if this invoked service could respond with "I've already done this", you know you can close the Saga immediately.